# numbering and duplicating files with odd and even numbers with script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sh

I'm trying to duplicate files and add odd numbers and even numbers at the end of them how can I do this?  I know I can use {001..10} sequentially but how can I make it do odd and or even numbers only.  PS this is bash script example.

```
for i in {001..10}; %want odd numbers 001,003,005,007,009
    do 
        cp talk_only_L1L2_18_feb_11_2016_.wav file-$i; 
done

for i in {001..10}; %want even numbers 002,004,006,008,010
    do 
        cp talk_only_L1L2_19_feb_11_2016_.wav file-$i; 
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that like this, for odd numbers

```
for i in {001..10..2}; ...
```

For even numbers it's similar, but you have to change the start

```
for i in {002..10..2}; ...
```

Comment: If your version of bash supports {m..n} but not the extended form, you can use the technique illustrated here: `for i in {001..10}; do echo $((2 * i)) ; done`.

Comment: @peak this will not really work for, e.g., `i=008`. And for values that don't contain the digits `8` and `9`, the leading `0`'s aren't preserved.

Comment: This was just a comment.  You can use e.g. printf to attain the padding.

Answer (score 1):

An approach with a  `while` loop, which will work in any POSIX-compatible shell.

```
i=0
while [ "$i" -le 10 ]; do
    if [ "$(i % 2)" = 0 ]; then
        # do even-file stuff
    else
        # do odd-file stuff
    fi
    i=$((i + 1))
done
```

With two loops,

```
i=0
while [ "$i" -le 10 ]; do
    # do even-file stuff
    i=$((i + 2))
done
i=1
while [ "$i" -le 10 ]; do
    # do odd-file stuff
    i=$((i + 2))
done
```

Comment: With the addition that the OP wants numbers like `001, 002`, not `1, 2` and he will then have to use `printf`, for example: `printf %03d $i`.